# Remove duplicates from a list containing a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a list containing a generic class. The generic class looks like this (stripped back example):

```
public class Point2D<T>
{
    public T x;
    public T y;

    public Point2D(T x, T y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

and I've created the list like this:

```
List<Point2D<int>> pointList = new List<Point2D<int>>();
pointList.Add(new Point2D<int>(1,1));
pointList.Add(new Point2D<int>(1,2));
pointList.Add(new Point2D<int>(1,1));
pointList.Add(new Point2D<int>(1,3));
```

I tried removing the duplicates by:

```
pointList = pointList.Distinct().ToList();
```

expecting that `pointList` would only contain: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) but it still contains all four points that were entered. I suspect I need my own equals or comparator method in `Point2D`, but I don't know if this is the case, or how they should be written (unless of course I'm just missing something simple).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you need to override [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
    public class Point2D<T>
    {
        public readonly T x;
        public readonly T y;

        public Point2D(T x, T y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Point2D<T>) obj);
        }

        protected bool Equals(Point2D<T> other)
        {
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, other.x) && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(y, other.y);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(x)*397) ^ EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, you need to override [GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx). But to do it correctly, you must make your `x` and `y` readonly fields

Comment: Good ol' resharper, eh?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes, it makes such thigs fast and easy

Comment: @Backs I'm not sure on the GetHashCode method, so will have to read up on it, but this is allowing my unit tests to pass. Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't implement `GetHashCode` based on mutable values as the value from `GetHashCode` **should never change over the lifetime of the object**. This object should be make immutable for this to be a good answer.

Comment: @Backs - Sorry to be a pain, but you should always override `GetHashCode` when overriding `Equals` as `Equals` only gets called when `GetHashCode` returns the same number. The correct thing to do is override neither or both, but not one only.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, yes. I really forgot about this. Updated with readdonly fields

Answer (score 3):

You can use Anonymous object. How ever this will change the references. so use it only when you do not need previous references.

```
pointList = pointList.Select(x => new {x.x,x.y}).Distinct().Select(x => new Point2D<int>(x.x, x.y)).ToList();
```

Comment: What's the `new {x.x,x.y}` doing? What type is that?

Comment: @Ayb4btu a custom compile time type which has read only properties. the name and the type of `new {x.x,x.y}` is generated by the compiler at compile time. read more about Anonymous object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement

```
IEquatable<T>
```

interface for this custom class. Check this link for more details and sample:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest overriding `==` operator. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) should help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.